# boost static_vector not std::is_trivially_destructible

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits, destroy

According to [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/B1mH9F) (left example)

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/container/static_vector.hpp>

struct X {
  int k;
  std::array<int, 4>                      a;
  boost::container::static_vector<int, 4> b;
  ~X() = default;
};

int huh()
{
  std::array<X, 5> x;
  return 0;
}
```

it looks like `boost::container::static_vector<T, N>` is trivially destructible when `T` is (there is no looping over `b` happening when an `X` gets destroyed). `huh` gets optimized to `xor eax, eax; ret` (i.e. `return 0` without looping over the array.

When I use instead a contained type that has a non trivial destructor (right example)

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/container/static_vector.hpp>

struct Y {
  ~Y();
};

struct X {
  int k;
  std::array<int, 4> a;
  boost::container::static_vector<Y, 4> b;
  ~X() = default;
};

int huh()
{
  std::array<X, 5> x;
  return 0;
}
```

there's a loop occuring

```
    add     rbx, 1
    call    Y::~Y() [complete object destructor]
    cmp     rbx, r12
    jne     .L3
```

I think this makes sense so far. The memory that's occupied by the static_vector with a trivially destructible object can just be released in constant time, regardless of how many objects are actually stored.

What surprises me is that the value of `std::is_trivially_destructible<boost::container::static_vector<int, 4> >::value` is false. Is this just an incorrect type trait?

Comment: Your first example doesn't say anything about the trivial-ness of the destructor, lots of code can be optimized away.

Comment: Have you tried it on multiple compilers?

Comment: @TanveerBadar yes, clang++ and icc agree with g++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boost::container::static_vector<X, N>` derives from `boost::container::vector<X, ...>` class which has some defined constructor. Even if all it's body is eliminated by compiler in release the class is already **not** trivially destructible:

```cpp
struct X
{
};

struct Y
{
    ~Y() = default;
};

struct Z
{
    ~Z() {};
};

static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<X>::value, ""); // Succeeds
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<Y>::value, ""); // Succeeds
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<Z>::value, ""); // Fails
```

That is the technical reason why it isn't in the current boost implementation. Can there be another implementation where `std::is_trivially_destructible<boost::container::static_vector<int, 4> >::value` is true? Yes, it's possible, but I suppose it requires a specialization of `boost::container::static_vector` for trivially destructible types.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::static_vector` inherits from `boost::vector`: https://github.com/boostorg/container/blob/develop/include/boost/container/static_vector.hpp#L106. Since `boost::~vector()` is non-trivial, thus is `boost::vector`, and `boost::static_vector` as well.

---

Note that your reasoning is wrong. In the second case, destructor calls cannot be optimized out, since the compiler does not see its definition. Try to change `Y();` to `~Y() { }`. A simple demo: https://godbolt.org/z/pg2xS4.

Why shouldn't be compilers allowed to optimize out non-trivial destructor calls if they have no observable effects?